# Any way to get angular-ui-bootstrap date picker to accept multiple formats for dates?

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

Using latest angular-ui-bootstrap and the date picker directive to do my date selections, but what I'd like to know is if it's possible to have the date picker select two different formats for a text box.

```
<input type="text" 
 class="form-control" 
 ng-model="vm.startDate" 
 uib-datepicker-popup="M/d/yyyy" 
 datepicker-options="vm.dateOptions" 
 close-text="Close" 
 is-open="vm.opened1" 
 placeholder="Start Date" 
 ng-required="false" 
 min-date="vm.minDate" 
 max-date="vm.maxDate" 
 init-date="vm.getCalendarInitDate()"
/>
```

the uib-datepicker-popup="M/d/yyyy" works fine for dates like 9/5/2015  but what about somebody who puts in 9/5/15?    It doesn't work out that.

Ideally, I'd like both of them to be acceptable.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

Seems that the issue (at least for days and months) has been fixed with this [commit](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/commit/b1cfc5762dd80d8eecec95385a4dcf335cdb8ecd). You can now define a day/month/year-date in format `d!.M!.yyyy`. It allows an optional leading zero for day and month. See this [github-issue](https://github.com/angular-ui/bootstrap/issues/4496) for more information.